# Passing Parameters from one page to another VB.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have two pages, Act_Summary and Details. On the Summary page they will be clicking a link that will take them to the details page. I am wanting 3 parameters, UserName, StartDate, and EndDate to pass to the details page whenever they click the link. But every time I click the link it is giving me this error:

> Object Reference Is not set to an instance of an object

This is my code on the Summary page:

```
    Dim SD As String = StartWebDatePicker.Value
    Dim ED As String = EndWebDatePicker.Value
    Dim UserName As String = e.Row.Items.FindItemByKey("UserName").Value

        ActSumm = "<a href = ""/Applications/Sales/Goldmine/GMActSummary/ActPopUps/Details.aspx?User=" & UserName & "&SD=" & SD & "&ED=" & ED & """ target=""_Blank""><b>Summary</b></a>"
```

and this is my code on the Details page:

```
    Dim UserName As String = Encryption64.Decrypt(Request.QueryString("UserName"))
    Dim StartDate As String = Encryption64.Decrypt(Request.QueryString("SD"))
    Dim EndDate As String = Encryption64.Decrypt(Request.QueryString("ED"))

    Page.Title = "" & UserName & "'s Activity Summary"

    Dim SqlString As String = "Select Username, SD, ED"

    Dim MyDataTable As DataTable = OleFun.GetMyDataTableString(SqlString)

    WebDataGrid1.DataSource = MyDataTable
    WebDataGrid1.DataBind()
```

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: I think your URL is malformed. Try using this `"<a href ='/Applications/Sales/Goldmine/GMActSummary/ActPopUps/Details.aspx?User=" + Username + "&SD=" + SD + "&ED=" + ED + "' target=_Blank><b>Summary</b></a>"`. Also, does your `Encryption64.Decrypt` method decrpts _NULL_. If not then add null check for decrypting any querystring this will overcome _Object Reference_ error.

Comment: When you hover above the link. Are you able to see proper URL?

Comment: Changing my URL didnt do anything, but how would i add null check to the decrypt? I haven't done that before, and yes it does show the proper url

Comment: when you look at the url, are the value encrypted? seems like you aren't. Also, on which line does the error happen? That error is easy to figure out, one of your object is equal to Nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha wow, the whole time was because I had the parameter named "user" in the URL and was decrypting it as UserName... *Face Palm*